# How can I see TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ in action with JDBC / MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, locking

I have MySQL Server (5.7.16) running on my computer currently, and have this sample row in a database called 'Sakila' on this Server:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM actor WHERE last_name = 'tugay';
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|      201 | koray      | tugay     | 2017-06-11 21:42:08 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

This is what JDBC returns for TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL for my MySQL Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
    final Connection connection = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "root", "root");
    System.out.println(connection.getTransactionIsolation()); // Prints 4!
    connection.close();
}
```

where `4` here is the constant for `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` which is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ) as follows:

```
int TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ  = 4;
A constant indicating that dirty reads are prevented. 
This level prohibits a transaction from reading a row with uncommitted changes in it.
```

I want to see this behavior so I have 2 main methods, first being:

```
import java.sql.*;

import static java.sql.DriverManager.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        final Connection connection = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "root", "root");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE actor SET first_name = 'ALTERED' WHERE first_name = 'koray'");

        System.out.println("Sleeping!");

        // Here I am expecting MySQL to lock the Row so no other Connection
        // can read data from it. This row will be updated, so unless the transaction is 
        // either commited or rolled back, the read data will be 'dirty'.
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        connection.commit();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

As you see, the transaction is **not** in auto-commit mode, and I am locking the row for 5 seconds. While this process is sleeping, I constantly run the following code as well:

```
public class Bar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
        final Connection connection = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila", "root", "root");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        final Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        final ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM actor WHERE last_name = 'tugay'");

        resultSet.next();
        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("first_name"));

        connection.close();
    }
}
```

But even I see "sleeping" text in the console, as long as I run the main method in Bar, I will see values like

```
koray
koray
koray
ALTERED
```

My expectation was **never to see koray** since that is a "dirty data", where the first java process should be locking the row.

What am I missing and how can I lock this row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the definition again:

> This level prohibits a transaction from reading a row with uncommitted
>   changes in it.

ALTERED is the dirty data, since it's not commited. Koray is the correct one. Bar is prohibited to see "ALTERED". You'll keep seeing "koray" as long as the transaction wasn't commited.

Comment: I do not think this answers my question.

Comment: @KorayTugay this *exactly* answers your question.  The isolation level prevents you from seeing the uncommitted value by showing you the value from before it was updated.  It does not prevent you from seeing the old value or make you wait. The row lock (an `X` lock) is indeed there, but for another transaction to block against it, the second transaction must try to obtain an incompatible lock.  If you want the behavior you describe, the second transaction must `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` (for as `IS` lock) or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (for an `IX` lock).

Comment: @KorayTugay could you please clarify then a bit more, what perplexes you?

Comment: I think I understand now, after Micael 's explanations. My expectations were wrong. My understanding was "koray" was the dirty datum, it seems "ALTERED" is the one who is dirty..

Comment: Can you please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501681/how-can-i-make-a-row-being-read-wait-until-a-lock-on-it-is-released-using-jdbc-a ? @Michael-sqlbot

Comment: Yes, reading back ALTERED would be a dirty read, because that means one thread was able to read data that had not yet been committed to the database.  Until that transaction commits -- which it might never do, since it coild also roll back -- it would be a dirty read if another transaction could see it, because that means another transaction was able to see something that was not in the database.